# Как очистить коллекцию в phalcon 3

Tags: php, mongodb, phalcon

Решили обновить Phalcon до версии 3.0, обновили PHP до 7. Работаем с MongoDB. Не нахожу в документации по ODM возможности дропнуть или очистить коллекцию (или всю бд). Как это сделать через ODM?

Comment: В итоге сделал через exec и вызов команды напрямую к базе.